# Create an output matrix from a table of pairs

Tags: sql

I have a table of roles versus permissions as such:

```
role | permission    
r1   | p1
r2   | p1
r2   | p2
r3   | p1
r3   | p2
r3   | p3
```

What I want is an output table where the columns are **(role and then each permissions)**. Where the permission/role pair exists in the table I want a 1, where it doesn't exist I want a 0.

Here is the output:

```
role | p1 | p2 | p3
r1   | 1  | 0  | 0
r2   | 1  | 1  | 0
r3   | 1  | 1  | 1
```

That is easy, but here is the kicker...**neither roles or permissions are fixed length, new ones can be added at any time so I need this to be taken into account.**

I don't think this is possible due to the nature of SQL but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Please add the expected output for the given data. Which database?

Comment: This is called "pivoting the table" and how it's done depends - as techdo already asked - on the used database system.

Comment: This is a valid question imo, but is a possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify what RDBMS you are using - so here are solutions for both MySQL and SQL Server.

**MySQL:**

This is a `PIVOT` but MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function so you will need to replicate it using an aggregate function and a `CASE` statement.

Static Version - is where you know all of the values beforehand:

```
select role,
  sum(case when permission = 'p1' then 1 else 0 end) p1,
  sum(case when permission = 'p2' then 1 else 0 end) p2,
  sum(case when permission = 'p3' then 1 else 0 end) p3
from yourtable
group by role;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47c76/6)

If you don't know the values to turn to column beforehand then you can use a prepared statement:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(case when permission = ''',
      permission,
      ''' then 1 else 0 end) AS ',
      permission
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM yourtable;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT role, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM yourtable 
                   GROUP BY role');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edc0b/1)

**SQL Server:**

There is a `PIVOT` function in sql server and you can either hard-code the values or use dynamic sql.

Static Version:

```
select *
from 
(
  select role, permission
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  count(permission)
  for permission in ([p1], [p2], [p3])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3cc1e/1)

Dynamic Version:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(permission) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT role, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select role, permission
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(permission)
                for permission in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f678/5)

The result from all versions is:

```
| ROLE | P1 | P2 | P3 |
-----------------------
|   r1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |
|   r2 |  1 |  1 |  0 |
|   r3 |  1 |  1 |  1 |
```